# GC friendly convex clipping (union and difference) algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, garbage-collection, geometry, clipping

I'm looking for algorithm that will cut my convex polygon based on another convex polygon. It is gonna be for destructible terrain (diff) and for creating terrain (union) in 2D map in game.

Algorithm has to be Garbage Collector friendly and the only boolean operations that are neccessary are Union & Difference.

I've done some research and there are some github projects, but all of them produce some garbage more or less.

https://github.com/tmpvar/2d-polygon-boolean

https://github.com/w8r/GreinerHormann

I guess the best solution would be to learn one of these and re-make it my way. But maybe you've heard about some that suits my needs?

Thanks.

Comment: "all of them produce some garbage more or less": what does this more or less means ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem involves two subproblems

1. find the intersection points between the two outlines
2. join the vertices that mus be joined.

For 1. you can exploit convexity: see both polygons as two monotone chains. When you travel the chains of the twopolygons simultaneously, say by increasing x, the intersections are detected when the ordinates cross each other between two abscissas.

For 2. notice that the union or difference are made of portions of the outlines alternating between one polygon and the other, at every interesection point.

Note that in the case of the difference, there can be several disconnected pieces.

[image]

I guess that you can implement this without any allocation/deallocation at all (but for the output polygon).